# How to read returned values from XMLHttpRequest call?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

I am having a problem with my XMLHttpRequest.  I do not want to use a jQuery wrapper so I need help getting the below to work.  How do I get to the data?  Also, my count seems to be wrong.  It return 3000 as the length.  I'm just trying to return the number of SharePoint list items the call returned.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var itemID = getQueryString("ID");
                            var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Document Approval')/items?$filter=(BackToAD eq 'Yes') and  (ID eq "+ itemID + ")";
                            console.log(endPointUrl);

                            var xReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xReq.open("GET", endPointUrl, true);
                            xReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
                            xReq.timeout = 2000;
                            xReq.ontimeout = function(){
                                            alert("timeout");
                            }
                            xReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                            if (xReq.readyState === 4){
                                            //alert("IN onready");
                                                            if (xReq.status === 200){
                                                                console.log("LENGTH: ");
                                                                            console.log(xReq.response.length);
                                                                            console.log("Text: ");
                                                                            //console.log(xReq.responseText);
                                                                            console.log(xReq.target.responseText);

                                                            } else {
                                                                            console.log("Fail");
                                                            }
                                            }
                            }
                            xReq.send();
```

Comment: The  `xReq.responseText` will have the json that will return your data. You then need to iterate through the json to get the data.

Comment: Even if it is returning 1 value?

Comment: But that one value will have the json which will have all the data you have requested.  If not then run this url `var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Document Approval')/items?$filter=(BackToAD eq 'Yes') and  (ID eq "+ itemID + ")";` in the browser to check how many values it is returning or you can also use postman for it